# I can't create new iOS 11 HomeKit automations

Tags: ios, homekit

When I go to create an automation on my iPad which shows as the home hub device and is updated to iOS 11 I see this message:

> To run automations based on other people's arrival or departure, make sure your home hub's software is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to toggle off and back on the home hub switch for my iPad and then the iOS 11 automations showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Not viable for many, but deleting and rebuilding my home enabled this feature. I use an ATV4 for a hub and tried disconnecting/reconnecting to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

- on Apple TV go to Settings -> Accounts -> iCloud
- click Sign Out
- click Sign In, input your iCloud credentials
- wait for the HomeKit section to appear in this screen
- select your home in the HomeKit section
- click it once to disconnect your home, click it again to connect it back
- Your devices should see the new capabilities of HomeKit.

Answer (score 1):

Miguel’s advice about signing out and back in to iCloud on the Apple TV didn’t work for me. I had to add the extra step of (temporarily) making my iPad Pro the home hub and then signing back into iCloud on the Apple TV.

1. on Apple TV, go to Settings -> Accounts -> iCloud
2. click Sign Out
3. on the iPad, go to Settings -> Home -> Use this iPad as a home hub
4. open the Home app to verify new automations are working
5. go back to Apple TV and sign in to iCloud again
6. wait for the HomeKit section to appear in this screen
7. select your home in the HomeKit section
8. click it once to disconnect your home, click it again to connect it back
9. on your iPad, go back to the Home app
10. on the bottom Home tab, tap the location services arrow icon at the top left. Confirm that your Apple TV shows as “connected” in the home hub section